# deployment dependencies condition skipped azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Created a pipeline. Have 2 stages. the stage job is deployment second stage has a condition derived from the first stage variable. the pipeline sample is given below

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: Staging
    displayName: Stage the WebApp
    environment: stg
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageOutputVar;isOutput=true]true"
            env:
              myVar: 'this is a stage output var'
            name: printvar

- stage: Swap
  dependsOn: Stage
  condition: eq(dependencies.Stage.Staging.outputs['Staging.printvar.myStageOutputVar'], 'true')
  variables:
    myVarfromStage: $[ stageDependencies.Stage.Staging.outputs['Staging.printvar.myStageOutputVar'] ]
  jobs:
  - deployment: Production
    displayName: Swap to production
    environment: adt
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo $(myVarfromStage)
```

the Swap - stage is getting skipped every time . Any changes need to do it in the condition ?

Comment: try to remove the second "Staging" from the condition: `dependencies.Stage.Staging.outputs['printvar.myStageOutputVar']`

Comment: tried that no luck. still it is skipped

Comment: and with `stageDependencies` instead of `dependencies`?

Comment: Same tried that. stage is skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you could look into [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-depending-on-job-output) for the expression.

You will need to edit your condition as below. Notice `Staging.Staging`

```
- stage: Swap
  dependsOn: Stage1
  condition: eq(dependencies.Stage1.outputs['Staging.Staging.printvar.myStageOutputVar'], 'true')
```